# Не правильная кодировка при выводе данных из бд

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, phpmyadmin, charset

У меня почему-то при выводе данных из бд, русские слова выводятся в не правильной кодировке, хотя есть

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");//устанавливаем кодировку бд
```

Что делать?
Вот полный код
https://pastebin.com/tLVVRBeN

Вот скриншот результата
[image: результат]

Он должен вывести

```
{"First_name":"Данил"}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95210/discussion-on-question-by-mr-danil-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$info = array('First_name' => iconv('UTF-8','CP1251',$info_user[first_name])); print_r($info);
```